# Scripts to spawn units with multiple navAgent destinations, and wait times using a Controller script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a spawn controller script. Fundamentally I'm also asking to see if there's a better way to do this?

What:
Every x seconds, SpawnController.cs selects a random unit, start, PitStop and final positions from a series of arrays.

It calls 'SpawnSingle.cs' with these variables.

'SpawnSingle.cs' instantiates the GameObject, sends the destination to 'navMove' script attached to the GameObject once when created, waits for x seconds when it arrives and changes destination.

Question:

- How do I make each instance of my called script (SpawnSingle)
  'wait' for x seconds midway, as it's controlling the gameObject. I
  can't use a coroutine to stop it.
- How do I pass in the second set of coordinates after? It doesn't
  seem to work when using the SpawnController.

  ```
  //In SpawnController.cs
  ...
  ...
  private Transform currentDestination;
  private NavMove moveScript;
  private GameObject newEnemy;
  public static SpawnSingle newSpawn = new SpawnSingle();

      void Start()
  {
      // To build a function to randomise the route and spawn at intervals
      spawnCounter = 0;
      Spawn();
      spawnCounter++;
      Spawn();

     void Spawn()
  {
      newSpawn.SpawnEnemy(Enemies[spawnCounter], SpawnPoint[spawnCounter], PitStop[spawnCounter], Destination[spawnCounter]);
  }
  ```

SpawnSingle.cs then assigns the first stop (pitStop) and tells it to move there using navAgents.

Problem:
When it arrives at PitStop location, I want it to wait for a few seconds, then continue on to the final destination.

This all worked OK for single instances without the Controller.

```
 // in SpawnSingle.cs
private Transform currentDestination;
private NavMove moveScript; // This script moves the navAgent
private GameObject newEnemy;
public void SpawnEnemy(GameObject Enemies, Transform SpawnPoint, Transform PitStop, Transform Destination)
{
    newEnemy = GameObject.Instantiate(Enemies, SpawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    moveScript = newEnemy.GetComponent<NavMove>();
    currentDestination = PitStop;
    moveScript.destination = currentDestination;

    if (arrivedAtP())
    {
    // Stop and wait x seconds
    moveScript.nav.enabled = false;
    // ***HELP HERE*** How do I make this script wait? Coroutines don't work when this script is called from an extenral source it seems?
    // Wait for x seconds--


    //Continue moving to final destination
    //*** HELP HERE*** When instantiated from an external script, this doesn't continue to pass in the new location?***
    moveScript.nav.enabled = true;
    currentDestination = Destination;
    moveScript.destination = currentDestination;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go about solving this is to make separate components for each behaviour.

Right now your spawner is responsible for 3 things:
1) making enemies, 2) setting initial nav points, 3) updating nav points later.

I would advise making your spawner only responsible for spawning objects.

Then make a navigator component that creates the nav points and pit stops etc.

so something like this:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
    //only spawns, attached to some gameobject
    public GameObject prefabToSpawn;

    public GameObject Spawn() {
        //instantiate etc..
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn);
        return newObject
    }

}

public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour {
    //attached to an empty gameObject
    public Spawner spawner;

    public Enemy CreateNewEnemy () {
        GameObject newEnemy = spawner.Spawn ();
        // add it to list of enemies or something
        //other stuff to do with managing enemies

    }



}

public class Navigator : MonoBehaviour {
    //Attached to Enemy prefab

    Destination currentDestination;

    public float changeDestinationTime;


    void Start() {
        currentDestination = //first place you want to go

        InvokeRepeating ("NewDestination", changeDestinationTime, changeDestinationTime);
    }


    void NewDestination() {
        currentDestination = // next place you want to go
    }

}
```

Obviously that's not a complete solution but it should help get you pointed in the right direction (and change directions every 8 secs :D ). Let me know if I misunderstood what you're trying to do!

Comment: That seems much cleaner, let me try that shortly. In EnemyManager, if I wanted it to create multiple concurrently, can I do the following:

for (i=0, i<5, i++)
{ CreateNewEnemy();}

Or will it override the current 'spawner' instance and leave me with only 1?

Comment: Yeah the spawner is just another game object in your scene, so you can reuse it as much as possible. Your for loop is the way to go.